What's the right ML model to predict x and y coordinates on a four quadrant graph?
This project is for a university class. I've collected data from Political Compass and I want to use it to approximate x coordinate and y coordinate values on the Political Compass using Twitter data. This is just a snippet:



key
twitter_user_id
politician_name
twitter_handle
x_coordinate
y_coordinate
political party
election year
country
twitter_active_during_election




8132862008
813286
Barack Obama
BarackObama
3
2
Democratic
2008
USA
TRUE


9390912008
939091
Joe Biden
JoeBiden
3
3
Democratic
2008
USA
TRUE


150226332008
15022633
Dennis Kucinich
Dennis_Kucinich
-2
-2
Democratic
2008
USA
TRUE


314286852008
31428685
Bill Richardson
GovRichardson
4
4
Democratic
2008
USA
FALSE


154165052008
15416505
Mike Huckabee
GovMikeHuckabee
6
6
Republican
2008
USA
TRUE



My professor told me to use two Logistic Regression models - one to approximate the x value and one to approximate the y. I want to make sure this is a viable approach. Based on what I've read online, it seems that Logistic Regression is a binary model. I couldn't find an example where it was offering an output other than yes/no or 1/0.
Can Logistic Regression approximate these values? If not, what model is the right approach for this project?
Edit: Someone has suggested polynomial or linear regression since the output is continuous. It is continuous. Ideally, the output would be an integer between -10 and 10.
